# ASP.NET MVC query lambda expression

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, linq, lambda

Hello I have problem in one query. Why it's always return no value.

```
public List<UserDetail> userSearchModel(UserSearchModel searchModel)
    {
        string userid = User.Identity.GetUserId();
        var user = _dbContext.UserDetails.Where(x => x.Id == userid);
        var result = _dbContext.UserDetails.Except(user).ToList().AsQueryable();          
        if (searchModel != null)
        {
            if (searchModel.LanguageId.Count() != 0)
            {
                List<UserDetailLanguage> usrDetails = new List<UserDetailLanguage>();
                foreach (var item in searchModel.LanguageId)
                {
                    var details = _dbContext.UserDetailLanguages.Where(x => x.LanguageId == item).ToList();
                    foreach (var item2 in details)
                    {
                        usrDetails.Add(item2);
                    }
                }            
                result = result.Where(x => x.UserDetailLanguages == usrDetails);
            }
        }         
        return result.ToList();
    }
```

I want to get results which are the same in usrDetails list and in result.UserDetailLanguages.
In result.UserDetailLanguages I have record equals to record in usrDetails but this not want retrieve.

Here is my model:

```
public class UserDetail
{
    public UserDetail()
    {
        this.UserDetailLanguages = new HashSet<UserDetailLanguage>();
    }
    [Key, ForeignKey("User")]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime Birthday { get; set; }
    public string Sex { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public string About { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public int Age { get { return DateTime.Now.Year - Birthday.Year; } }
    public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<UserDetailLanguage> UserDetailLanguages { get; set; }

}
public class UserDetailLanguage
{
    public Int32 Id { get; set; }

    public virtual UserDetail UserDetail { get; set; }
    public string UserDetailId { get; set; }
    public virtual Language Language { get; set; }
    public Int32 LanguageId { get; set; }
    public Boolean IsKnown { get; set; }
    public static implicit operator List<object>(UserDetailLanguage v)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
public class Language
{
    public Language()
    {
        this.UserDetailLanguages = new HashSet<UserDetailLanguage>();
    }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<UserDetailLanguage> UserDetailLanguages { get; set; }
}
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: *"I want to get results which are the same in usrDetails list and in result.UserDetailLanguages."* <== this makes no sense.  you will have to explain better or give us an example.

Comment: For example: I have User who have some properties and one of this is list of languages. Now I want to search only this users which have selected languages. In usrDetails I store selected languages and now I want to find this users which have one of this languages

Comment: this makes little sense but I note this "have **one** of this languages".  Probably want to use something other than `=`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to see if your value is in a list you use the Contains function of the list -- like this:

```
  result = result.Where(x => usrDetails.Contains(x.UserDetailLanguage));
```

If you want to see if there are any items in both lists you can use intersection like this:

```
 result = result.Where(x => usrDetails.Intersect(x.UserDetailLanguage).Count() > 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are checking equality between lists in following code

```
result = result.Where(x => x.UserDetailLanguages == usrDetails);
```

This might not work, to check equality for lists you can use something like

```
Enumerable.SequenceEqual(FirstList.OrderBy(fList => fList), 
                     SecondList.OrderBy(sList => sList))
```